# ionic navigation not working and giving cannot find module path

Tags: ionic-framework

[This is the error , i have checked everything in my modules and component and there is nothing missing (click to see photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1szK0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second-page import path is wrong please change it

```
import { SecondPage } from '../second/second'
```

i hope its work for you.